# Symfony Form Choices Entity

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I try to use the '[choices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)' option into my form :

```
class FicheInterventionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

            ->add('services', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'        => 'GestionBundle:Service',
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'multiple'     => true,
                'choices'      => $options['services'],
                'required'     => false))

        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FichesBundle\Entity\FicheIntervention',
            'services' => null
        ));
    }
}
```

controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(FicheInterventionType::class, $ficheObservation,
    array('services' => $this->getUser()->getCategorie()->getServices()));
```

but I get all services present in my database, not the services passed with the parameter $option.

I don't know why.

Comment: You cannot pass services this way. Maybe extending the `EntityType` with your custom `ServicesType` and inject the `@token_storage` into that. 



Another way would be ditching the EntityType and directly work with the ChoiceType. This would then need custom DataTransformers.

Comment: It should work this way. Are you sure your query doesn't provide all services present in your database ?

Comment: Of course i'm sure ;p

Comment: And if you do an exit(dump($options['services'])); in buildForm ?

Comment: I get 'null'. It's not this way to pass parameters ?

Comment: I found my error  ... I was in the wrong controller (FicheObservation instead of FicheIntervention). My bad, sorry.